# Why firefox 10.1 uses full screen on Snow Leopard while Chrome and Safari do not?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, google-chrome, fullscreen

I am new to the Mac World, I am stuck with the fact that on my 15 inch Mac Book Pro only Firefox 10.1 uses all the screen, while Chrome and Safari only use a portion of it. Chrome is the thing I miss most because it's the browser I usually use.

How do I set it to use the full screen space?

I use Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) - it's something that I feel OSX needs and that would allow you to set a shortcut for it. Otherwise the green orb on the top left will take you to full height, and then you can drag out horizontally to your chosen width.

Alternatively, should you upgrade to Lion, Chrome has a full-screen mode which hides all the other apps.

Comment: Ok, i didn't spot the "Drag me to full screen icon" and thought that the green button would take me directly to full screen!

Comment: Chrome's full screen mode works on pre-Lion as well.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X doesn't resize windows like Windows when maximized. Logically, having a browser window take up an entire screen is very verrrrryyy inefficient, since you end up with the two blank spaces on both sides. OS X makes a window big enough to show the content, but no bigger as to prevent wasting of screen space.

You can of course look for utilities to restore a more windows familiar feel - some I am aware of are moom, cinch, and [divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/). A [tutorial on using RightZoom may help as well](http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/make-the-os-x-maximize-button-work-like-windows/).

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, plus using the entire screen can be efficient for some sites, particularly with laptops.